# Angle of depression confusion

Tags: trigonometry

I was helping someone with a question and got a different answer to the one given in the book.

The question is: $A$ is standing at the top of a $220m$ tall cliff. The angle of depression from $A$ to a nearby house is $32^{\circ}$. How far is the house from the base of the cliff?

My diagram of the question was as follows.
[image]

According to this, the value of $x$ should be $\frac {220} {tan(32^{\circ})}= 352.073 $. But the answer given is $220\tan(32^{\circ})= 137.47$.

Am I making a careless mistake or is the answer wrong?

Comment: Your answer is correct. The diagram is workable but not truly reflects the situation.

Comment: @Mick Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided answer in the book, $137.47$, makes no sense.  It implies that the distance from the base of the cliff to the house is smaller than the height of the cliff, which would immediately imply that the angle of depression is greater than $45^\circ$, and this clearly is not the case.

The fact that the angle of depression is $32^\circ$ suggests that the triangle in your diagram is close to a $30-60-90$ right triangle, meaning that the ratio of the lengths of the horizontal leg to the vertical leg is approximately $\sqrt{3} : 1$.  Moreover, since $32^\circ > 30^\circ$, this ratio is an overestimate; hence $x$ should be smaller than $220 \sqrt{3} \approx 381$.  Your answer is consistent with this.